# No VIDEO on boot

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2, nvidia

Sometimes, on boot, the **boot resolution gets low** (something arround 680x400) and after the boot I can't see the screen. Normally I solve it by reinstallng NVIDIA drivers or Loading the Default Configuration on BIOS. Sometimes it works, sometimes it does not!

This time I tried several things and I am now writting through Teamviewer on my phone.

So the computer starts but it can not show the image properly.

When I am starting the computer I already know if its gonna work or not: If the ASUS screen apears it's OK otherwise it will not show the image.

When it dows not work its shows very briefely (miliseconds) a JMICRON screen saing the driver was not find.

- Kubuntu 18.10 - Kernel 4.18.0-18-generic
- P67B3 motherboard with a video card NVIDIA ASUS 1060.
- 3 HDS: 1 ext4 (boot) and 2 NTFS.

I would not like to reinstall the system. I already done it and the issue persists.

I have been having this problem for months so I dont think its kernel related.
I am grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

With nvidia drivers it can happen when the kernel DKMS modules are not handled properly during updates.

You can manualy trigger this via terminal using:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure nvidia-dkms-390
```

Then reboot.

**troubleshooting**

Also make sure that there is nothing like `nomodeset` in your /etc/default/grub

```
cat /etc/default/grub | grep ^GRUB_CMDLINE
```

It should be:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
>
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

**nomodeset hunting**

It's also good idea to look for it in other places:

```
grep nomodeset /etc/ -rs
```

The only place you should see it is `/etc/grub.d/10_linux`

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_RECOVERY="$GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_RECOVERY nomodeset"

**xorg.conf**

Also if `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` is present you can try to rename it for the purpose of debuging:

```
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.bak
```

In case it doesn't help you can simply rename it again later on to bring back your settings:

```
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf.bak /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

There are also `nvidia-settings` and `nvidia-xconfig` that are worth of trying for changing stuff and recreating xorg.conf from scratch.

Here's mine, with settings that helps me work around screen tearing:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    Option         "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {ForceCompositionPipeline=On, ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On}"
    Option         "AllowIndirectGLXProtocol" "off"
    Option         "TripleBuffer" "on"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems it worked its been almost 10 days without the problem!